# Scrapy Shell extract text only from div class element

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to pull only the dates values from this site http://www.nflweather.com/

I believe I have the code but I need to clean up the result a little bit

```
response.xpath('//div[@class="fw-bold text-wrap"]/text()').extract()
```

My result returns \n\t

```
'\n\t\t\t12/28/23 08:15 PM EST\n\t\t'
```

I am looking to just get a nice clean date and time. I have see some other version here that do it in the script I would like to be able to have it done from the Scrapy shell.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `Selector.re` method to apply a regular expression to each matching selector in the group.  If you are only wanting the date then you could do something like `(?:\d{2}/?){3}` as the regex pattern.

For example using scrapy shell:

```
In [1]: fetch('http://www.nflweather.com/')
2023-12-31 19:07:51 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2023-12-31 19:07:51 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://www.nflweather.com/> from <GET http://www.nflweather.com/>
2023-12-31 19:07:51 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.nflweather.com/> (referer: None)

In [2]: response.xpath('//div[@class="fw-bold text-wrap"]/text()').re(r"(?:\d{2}/?){3}")
Out[2]:
['12/28/23',
 '12/30/23',
 '12/31/23',
 '12/31/23',
 '12/31/23',
 '12/31/23',
 '12/31/23',
 '12/31/23',
 '12/31/23',
 '12/31/23',
 '12/31/23',
 '12/31/23',
 '12/31/23',
 '12/31/23',
 '12/31/23',
 '12/31/23']
```

---

Edit:

If you want to keep the time also then i simply suggest calling `strip()` on the results of the selector query:

```
lst = response.xpath('//div[@class="fw-bold text-wrap"]/text()').getall()
[i.strip() for i in lst]
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. Code works but cout it not remove time. I am only getting dates. Can I get date and time back?